# java deserializing and serializing in the same process

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm having problems serializing and deserializing a list of objects in the same JVM. To be exact, right now my objects hold the same reference to an `Alphabet` object, which has the following rules:

```
    VMID instanceId = new VMID();  //used in readResolve to identify persitent instances

    public Alphabet (int capacity, Class entryClass) {
        this.map = new gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap (capacity);
        this.entries = new ArrayList (capacity);
        this.entryClass = entryClass;
        // someone could try to deserialize us into this image (e.g., by RMI).  Handle this.
        deserializedEntries.put (instanceId, this);
    }

    public VMID getInstanceId() {
        return instanceId;
    } // for debugging

    public void setInstanceId(VMID id) { this.instanceId = id; }

    // Serialization
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    private static final int CURRENT_SERIAL_VERSION = 1;

    private void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt (CURRENT_SERIAL_VERSION);
        out.writeInt (entries.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            out.writeObject (entries.get(i));
        }
        out.writeBoolean (growthStopped);
        out.writeObject (entryClass);
        out.writeObject(instanceId);
    }

    private void readObject (ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int version = in.readInt ();
        int size = in.readInt();
        entries = new ArrayList (size);
        map = new gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap (size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Object o = in.readObject();
            map.put (o, i);
            entries. add (o);
        }
        growthStopped = in.readBoolean();
        entryClass = (Class) in.readObject();
        if (version >0 ){ // instanced id added in version 1S
            instanceId = (VMID) in.readObject();
        }
    }

    private transient static HashMap deserializedEntries = new HashMap();
    /**
     * This gets called after readObject; it lets the object decide whether
     * to return itself or return a previously read in version.
     * We use a hashMap of instanceIds to determine if we have already read
     * in this object.
     * @return
     * @throws ObjectStreamException
     */

    public Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        Object previous = deserializedEntries.get(instanceId);
        if (previous != null){
            //System.out.println(" ***Alphabet ReadResolve:Resolving to previous instance. instance id= " + instanceId);
            return previous;
        }
        if (instanceId != null){
            deserializedEntries.put(instanceId, this);
        }
        //System.out.println(" *** Alphabet ReadResolve: new instance. instance id= " + instanceId);
        return this;
    }
```

Now afte deserialization of my list of objects, at some point the Alphabet references doesnt match up. I did a check using the following:

```
for (Instance i: finalTrainingDocs){
    if (!i.getTargetAlphabet().equals(finalTraining.getTargetAlphabet())){
        System.out.println("not equals");
        System.out.println(i.getTargetAlphabet().getInstanceId() + " " + finalTraining.getTargetAlphabet().getInstanceId());
    }
    finalTraining.add(i);
    counter++;
    System.out.println("counter " + counter);
}
```

And got back the following results

```
counter 237
counter 238
counter 239
not equals
3ce62156867eb540:6b7f0de5:141e51fcd67:-7ffa 3ce62156867eb540:6b7f0de5:141e51fcd67:-7ffa
```

Now looking at the VMId, since they are the same, shouldn't it be the same object, as of the logic above? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Those writeObject() and readObject() methods don't appear to add any value over what happens by default.

Comment: Seems like it. Its from an open source library called mallet so I'm not sure what's the intentions of the author there

Comment: I don't think there's enough code to figure out what is going on here.  For instance, how is `Alphabet.equals` implemented, and where is the code for VMID?

Comment: Hi Stephen there's no equals implementation in alphabet so it takes ==, the vmid  is this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/dgc/VMID.html

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have a race condition; i.e. two threads are updating the `deserializedEntries` hashmap at the same time.  That could result in you having two `Alphabet` instances with equal `instanceId` values.

Declaring the `deserializedEntries` as `volatile` is not sufficient to prevent this.  (And indeed, your inadequate synchronization might even lead to the hashmap' internal data structures being corrupted.)

---

I'm not convinced that what you are doing is a good idea.  In addition to this fragility (which requires more heavy-weight synchronization to fix), you have the problem that the hashmap is a memory leak.  I suspect you will get better performance by accepting that `Alphabet` instances get duplicated, and overriding `equals` to deal with this.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading instanceId  based on version

```
if (version >0 ){ // instanced id added in version 1S
    instanceId = (VMID) in.readObject();
}
```

So the same condition need to apply here

```
 if (CURRENT_SERIAL_VERSION >0 ){ 
      out.writeObject(instanceId);
```

Comment: Why do you think so? Add it where? Explain.

Comment: Bytecode, version was 1 all along so I don't think it might cause a problem...?